# 2012 Moderator Election: Town Hall Chat

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I will be working with candidates to determine a time for the event.

***The Town Hall Chat took place Wednesday the 5th at 01:00:00Z UTC / This is on Tuesday the 4th at 8:00 PM EST. A digest is available [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2768/2012-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest).***

Here are the details so far:

- I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the primary phase.  This means that I am looking at the 3rd-5th of December. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=physics.stackexchange.com).  I will update this post with a direct link to the chat room once the event is scheduled.
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- Priority for scheduling is generally towards the greatest number of candidate openings as well as the earliest. Candidates who cannot show up during the live event will still be able to answer all questions posted, they will just do so at their earliest convenience.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: By the looks of it, we may not _have_ primaries. Will that make the THC happen earlier? 5th is too late in that case :S

Comment: @Manishearth If there is no primary phase, it just happens at the start of the nomination phase.

Comment: Grace: for what it's worth, we have a biweekly chat session scheduled on  December 4 at 11 AM EST. That would be a fine time to hold the town hall chat if it works with your other scheduling requirements.

Comment: @Dilaton I figured it'd be easier to just delete the question. All those who were suggested have had time to become aware of the election and to nominate themselves if they wanted to.

Comment: @Dilaton it won't take away your badge, though next time you would have earned one (on meta), it will make that one the one that appears in your profile - so you won't get an additional badge at that time. I did see your email and I'll get back to you on that soon.

Comment: Darn, the sheduled time is 2.00 in the morning for me ... :-(

Comment: Its exactly 6-30 for me (an hour before I start out to college). Thank you Grace Note.