# Where is the place for negative comments on candidates?

Tags: discussion, support, election

I have a negative comment to make about a candidate. Where is the appropriate place to post this today? Where does it go? Not a week ago. I checked the meta and the main a week ago, and I didn't see his name on the nominations list.

Answer (score 13):

I guess if you wanted to create a place for negative comments, you would have to also create a place for positive comments.

**Anyone** can run for this - I even considered it. You **do not** need to be a specialist in your field to be a moderator. You simply need to:

- be able to listen
- support the wider community (not necessarily a vocal individual)
- take actions when they are required
- carry out janitorial tasks
- and generally help the community get along.

You say he considers you a crackpot. You consider him an authoritarian. Both these views could be true (or maybe not - I don't know). Does this mean you should create a post attacking that individual? I don't think so!

You will get to ask questions during the Town Hall tonight (or whenever it is in your timezone) but again - be polite while asking!

Answer (score 11):

There are several ways to express your opinion of a specific candidate. The first one you missed, it happens during the nomination period where every Physics user can comment on the nomination.

The second major opportunity to critically examine the candidates is during the townhall meeting, which takes place in a few hours. Of course not everyone can attend, but if you have a specific question you want to ask the candidates, just post it in Physics chat and request that someone else asks your question.

But you're after something else, you're not critically examining the history of a candidate on this site and asking them for their opinion on subject important to this site. You're trying to shout your opinion about this candidate at every opportunity you get, in chat on meta and even on the main site. Just because you're the loudest one right now doesn't mean your opinion deserves special consideration.

On the accusations of censorship, as already mentioned by SE employees, you're free to express your opinion as long as you don't resort to personal attacks and insults. You can criticize the actions and statements of a candidate as much as you want, but you don't get to just insult them. You're just plain wrong when you say that "being a dick" is required to have an honest discussion, you can be blunt and direct without ever insulting anyone.

If you are concerned about a specific candidate, ask targeted questions about your concerns at the town hall, or if you can't attend ask someone else to do that for you. Make it about actual concerns, not about your own opinion of the candidate.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with Ron's point of view and I'm a bit troubled by this whole election process. 
There are finally enough decent candidates that I hope it will turn out well, but a few days ago I would not have liked to see any set of two new moderators chosen from what was available.

I have serious concerns about the future of the site if our new moderators turn out to be people with little knowledge of physics, reputation or time spent in the community.

And if someone with 40,000 reputation (earned by being a valuable contributing member to the site) has criticisms of a candidate, I think it would be smart to listen to him.

Answer (score 5):

There is an election oriented chat tonight (Tuesday) at 8pm EST.

A summary of the questions and answers will be posted to Meta following the conclusion of the event.

Note that the summary is limited to the questions directed at the candidates and direct answers by the candidates, since collecting those is the entire purpose of the event. For more info, see: [2012 Moderator Election: Town Hall Chat](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2668/2012-moderator-election-town-hall-chat)