# What changes will the upcoming election bring?

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

So, [apparently](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9154/2016-moderator-election-qa-question-collection), we're 'scheduled' to have a moderator election later this month. What changes, exactly, will this election entail? Are any of the [existing moderators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) stepping down? How many new moderators will be elected? Is the number of moderators changing? If so, does this mean that the current load is more than what's reasonable for the current crew to handle as effectively as they'd like?

Comment: I mentioned some of these points in the [hbar chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32331390#32331390) on Sept. 15th, 2016.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very brief answers:

1. The main change is the addition of two moderators to make the work load easier on the existing moderation team.
2. No.
3. Two new moderators will be elected.
4. Yes, see above.
5. David Z elaborated a bit on this:

   > When all four of us are available, we have no problem with the current workload. But if a couple mods are traveling or without internet access, it becomes hard to keep up, and that happens often enough that we'd like to expand the moderation team to avoid being shorthanded.

For a bit more general information, see [the chat transcript linked by Qmechanic in the comments](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32331390#32331390). This is all that's known, for now.