# 2016 Moderator Election Chat October 4 16:00 UTC

Tags: discussion, election

**The election chat has concluded; see [the transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45927/conversation/2016-election-chat-session).**

---

Our next [regularly scheduled chat session](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/71/the-h-bar?tab=schedule), October 4 at 16:00 UTC/12:00 EDT, will be devoted to the current election. We'll be holding the session in [our dedicated election chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45927/2016-physics-stack-exchange-election), *not* in [the main site chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) as we usually do.

The *tentative* plan is to split the session into two parts:

1. A few minutes at the beginning to address any procedural questions about the election process. (Of course, such questions can also be posted here on meta at any time.)
2. The remainder of the session will be open for anyone to ask the candidates questions on the topic of moderation. I hope to run this in town-hall style, as done in [our last election](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2668/2012-moderator-election-town-hall-chat). This will complement the [existing questionnaire](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9196/2016-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire) by allowing for more back-and-forth discussion.

I'll update this post with further details as we work them out.

(Yes, this is an announcement, not a question.)

Comment: For how long will the discussion extend? I ask because I'm on central time and I'd be available at 11:46 to 12:36 central time (or 16:46 to 17:36 UTC).

Comment: At least an hour - at least, the official chat session will last an hour. People might stick around afterwards and continue the discussion if they like.